Flask-SQLAlchemy db.create_all() issue fixed, but now get 404 error
I tried to run my code to set up a database using flask and I got this error. I did some research and figured out how to fix it using the:
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    print('Created Database')

However, now when I try to launch my website I get a 404 error. It all worked just fine before I added this step and can't figure out what I did wrong.... Any ideas?
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asdf;lkj'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Note

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        print('Created Database!')

    return app

My code was originally this:
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asdf;lkj'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .models import User, Note

    return app

def create_database(app):
     if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
         db.create_all(app=app)
     print('Created Database!')

This was giving me a TypeError. Once I changed it to with app.app_context()..... it created the file 'database.db', but when I go to 127.0.0.1:5000 to see the website, I get a 404 error.
